# Equivalence test: when two sets are not disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = A_{1} \cup A_{2}$ such that, $A_{1} \cap A_{2} \neq \emptyset$. Given the relation $xRy \Leftrightarrow x, y \in  A_{1}$ or $x, y \in  A_{2}$. Is $R$ an equivalence relation?

Comment: $R$ is transitive when one of the two sets contains the other or when the intersection is empty. Otherwise, it's not transitive.

Comment: Well is it reflexive.  Is every element in the same set as itself?  Is it symetric?  If x is in the same set as y does that mean y is in the same set as x?  Is it transitive? If x and y are in the same set and y and z are in the same set, does it follow that x and z are in the same set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation is not transitive.

Example:

Let the sets $A_{1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x\geq 0\}$ and $A_{2}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ \mid x\leq 0\}$ then $\mathbb{R}=A_{1}\cup A_{2}$ and $\{0\}=A_{1}\cap A_{2}$.

Thus $\{-1\} R\{ 0\}$ and $\{0\} R\{ 1\}$ but $\{-1\}$ is not in the same set that $\{1\}$ then the transitive property does not follow.

Comment: You can obtain the vertical bar that means such that by typing \mid when you are in math mode.